# Using POSIX non-greedy RegEx in Textpad

Tags: regex, textpad

My Textpad is configed to use POSIX-style RegEx for searches.  I am trying to do a non-greedy search for text within parenths, including the parenths, so I am doing:

`\(.+?\)`

I was hoping that `?` would activate a non-greedy search (it does, for example, in Java RegEx) but it did not.  I cannot do a non-greedy search because I have sections like:

`(prnth_content_1) reg_textA (prnth_content_2) reg_textB (prnth_content_3) reg_textC`

and I want my search to stop for each parenthesized match group one-by-one, instead, it goes until the last closed parenth on the line returning

`(prnth_content_1) reg_textA (prnth_content_2) reg_textB (prnth_content_3)`

Any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: TextPad doesn't support the non-greedy syntax.

Comment: well, that's kind of lame of them...  thanks anyway.  i will move my file to linux and do it in vim...

Answer (score 4):

Use a character class and search for a "not parenthesis".

e.g.

```
\([^)]+\)
```